# Breadth and Depth First Search in Java

Tags: java

BFS and DFS in Java. Please give suggestions!!

```
Class Main {
    public void bfs()
    {
        // BFS uses Queue data structure
        Queue queue = new LinkedList();
        queue.add(this.rootNode);
        printNode(this.rootNode);
        rootNode.visited = true;
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = (Node)queue.remove();
            Node child=null;
            while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(node))!=null) {
                child.visited=true;
                printNode(child);
                queue.add(child);
            }
        }
        // Clear visited property of nodes
        clearNodes();
    }

    public void dfs() {
        // DFS uses Stack data structure
        Stack stack = new Stack();
        stack.push(this.rootNode);
        rootNode.visited=true;
        printNode(rootNode);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Node node = (Node)s.peek();
            Node child = getUnvisitedChildNode(n);
            if(child != null) {
                child.visited = true;
                printNode(child);
                s.push(child);
            }
            else {
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        // Clear visited property of nodes
        clearNodes();
    }
}


Class Node {
   Char data;
   Public Node(char c) {
      this.data=c;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we count the distance as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seem to be some inconsistencies here. What is `s`? I guess this is the stack? Also declaring a class Main is a little strange. You certainly want to have a main method, but a Main class?

Also I'd suggest you not use raw collections e.g. replace

```
Queue queue = new LinkedList();
```

with

```
Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
```

You may like to consider implementing DFS recursively so that you don't have to explicitly use a stack, although that's a matter of taste. Also, where is `getUnvisitedChildNode()` defined?  Where are the edges of the graph actually stored? This could be e.g. an adjacency list carried around by each node, or perhaps in another object, but it should be somewhere.

Comment: Also it make sense to replace Stack stack = new Stack(); with Deque<Node> s = new LinkedList<Node>();

Answer (score 3):

It is better to name the functions as breadth-first traversal, or depth-first traversal instead, as you didn't look up any element, but travelled all the nodes.
Quite trivial though :)

Answer (score 3):

**LinkedList** supports both **Stack** as well as **Queue** operations. So you can use this for both cases. Also if you are using Java 6+, better use Deque Interface instead of Queue.  (Deque extends Queue).

So your stack and queue declaration should be like below (for Java 6+ )

```
Deque<Node> queue = new LinkedList<Node>();
Deque<Node> stack = new LinkedList<Node>();
```